# Can JAXB Incrementally Marshall An Object?

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I've got a fairly simple, but potentially large structure to serialize.  Basically the structure of the XML will be:

```
<simple_wrapper>
   <main_object_type>
     <sub_objects>
   </main_object_type>
     ... main_object_type repeats up to 5,000 times
</simple_wrapper>
```

The `main_object_type` can have a significant amount of data.  On my first 3,500 record extract, I had to give the JVM way more memory than it should need.

So, I'd like to write out to disk after each (or a bunch of) `main_object_type`.

I know that setting `Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT` would allow it fragments, but I loose the outer xml document tags and the `<simple_wrapper>`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following?

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext= JAXBContext.newInstance(MainObjectType.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);

// Manually open the root element
writer.write("<simple_wrapper>");

// Marshal the objects out individually
marshaller.marshal(mainObjectType1, writer);
marshaller.marshal(mainObjectType2, writer);
marshaller.marshal(mainObjectType3, writer);
marshaller.marshal(mainObjectType4, writer);
...

// Manually close the root element
writer.write("</simple_wrapper>");
writer.close();
```

This assumes you have an @XmlRootElement on MainObjectType

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MainObjectType {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can marshal your object into a SAX or StAX stream.

Comment: If I use a stream, won't the standard method of creating a `JAXBElement<?>` for the `<simple_wrapper>` still require all the contained objects to be held in memory?  What I'm looking for is how to break it up without having to incur a lot of manual work with writing the `<xml>` headers, etc.  I want to open the `<simple_wrapper>` and write each `<main_object_type>` as they are retrieved from the DB, without too much monkey work.

Comment: Try using @XmlID with a custom IDResolver:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/15/pluggable-ididref-handling-jaxb-20

Your simple wrapper will only store the ids of objects and retrieve object instances via the id resolver.